# HttpExchange send file

Tags: java, httpserver

I am using my server to distribute some files (in a zip), however, I want the user to enter a CAPTCHA before being able to download the file.

This presents a new problem, because the code:

```
    private void sendFileResponse(final String filename, byte[] response, HttpExchange httpExchange) {
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="code">
        if (response != null && response.length > 0 && httpExchange != null) {
            try {
                httpExchange.setAttribute(HTTPExchange.HeaderFields.Content_Type.toString(), "application/zip");
                
                OutputStream outputStream = httpExchange.getResponseBody();
                httpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length);
                outputStream.write(response);
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
                httpExchange.getRequestBody().close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(Misc.getStackTrace(e));
            }
        }
        //</editor-fold>
    }
```

... will cause the file to be named as the download request webpage's URL. For example, if a user enters the correct CAPTCHA and downloads the file at /download.html, the file they receive would be download.html, not my file's name.

How do I make the server send the file as the file's name and cause the webpage to refresh at the same time?

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate, but can't seem to find the original right now...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the **Content-Disposition** HTTP header field:

Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=yourfilename

```
httpExchange.getResponseHeaders().add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
```

Comment: @user3635998 Try using httpExchange.getResponseHeaders().add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + ";");

Comment: I just got it working with the same thing and have edited your reply. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I added the code to the answer. You should always use getRequestHeaders() or getResponseHeaders(). I don't really know what setAttribute() is good for, but the other two sound quite straightforward.